# Looking for some assistance to transform a piece of PS code to v4

Tags: pine-script

Currently trying to convert an indicator (currently v2 or v3) to v4 in order to incorporate it with other strategies that I'm using, but running into issues since I'm not a very advanced coder. Code is below, error messages I receive are below that. Issue might be that L0 etc has not been defined previously, how do I circumvent that?

Thanks in advance!

```
study(title = "CM_Laguerre PPO PercentileRank Mkt Tops & Bottoms", shorttitle="CM_Laguerre PPO PctRank Tops-Bottoms", overlay=true, precision=1)
pctile = input(100, title="Percentile Threshold Extreme Value, Exceeding Creates Colored Histogram")
wrnpctile = input(90, title="Percentile Threshold Warning Value, Exceeding Creates Colored Histogram")
Short = input(0.4, title="PPO Setting")
Long = input(0.8, title="PPO Setting")
lkbT = input(200,title="Look Back Period For 'Tops' Percent Rank is based off of?")
lkbB = input(200,title="Look Back Period For 'Bottoms' Percent Rank is based off of?")
sl=input(true,title="Show Threshold Line?")
swl=input(true,title="Show Warning Threshold Line?")

lag(g, p) =>
    L0 = (1 - g)*p+g*nz(L0[1])
    L1 = -g*L0+nz(L0[1])+g*nz(L1[1])
    L2 = -g*L1+nz(L1[1])+g*nz(L2[1])
    L3 = -g*L2+nz(L2[1])+g*nz(L3[1])
    f = (L0 + 2*L1 + 2*L2 + L3)/6
    f
```

**Errors**

> line 17: Undeclared identifier 'L0';

> line 18: Undeclared identifier 'L1';

> line 19: Undeclared identifier 'L2';

> line 20: Undeclared identifier 'L3';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the variables `L0`, `L1`, `L2` and `L3` in the function `lag()`

```
lag(g, p) =>
    L0 = 0.0
    L1 = 0.0
    L2 = 0.0
    L2 = 0.0
    L0 := (1 - g)*p+g*nz(L0[1])
    L1 := -g*L0+nz(L0[1])+g*nz(L1[1])
    L2 := -g*L1+nz(L1[1])+g*nz(L2[1])
    L3 := -g*L2+nz(L2[1])+g*nz(L3[1])
    f = (L0 + 2*L1 + 2*L2 + L3)/6
    f
```

Comment: Ah, I suspected it would be something this simple, shame I couldn't figure it out myself. This solved the issue, much appreciated!